# Silent freebsd update between release

Tags: freebsd

I want to perform the FreeBSD upgrade between releases (from 9.1 to 9.2). Generally the sequence of actions is the following:

```
freebsd-update fetch
freebsd-update upgrade -r 9.2-RELEASE
freebsd-update install
```

Is it possible to do this without answering to the questions during the second step (like how to merge the config files), i.e. to perform the installation in "silent mode"?

It is important for me because I need to migrate between releases on 50 hosts. For that reason the number of questions should be the minimum. 
Is there maybe an opportunity to create pre-configuration file which will contain the answers to the future questions? Appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `yes` utility, which simply prints `y`'s into stdout. You can pipe it's output to `freebsd-update` to achieve unattended install:

```
yes | freebsd-update upgrade -r 9.2-RELEASE
```

As for `freebsd-update fetch`, it's used to download patches for current release, so if you are upgrading, you need only `upgrade` and `install`.